# How to define custom date format in page.tpl.php?

Tags: 7

I would like to add a custom copyright footer to my site e.g. MONTH YEAR. I have set up a »short« date format for English, French and German in admin/config/regional/date-time/locale. Using `<?php print format_date(time(), 'custom', t('F Y')); ?>` in page.tpl.php is working great.

However I would love to go one step further. How do I print the short date format to page.tpl.php instead of adding them to *.tpl files separately?

Comment: Just `<?php print format_date(time(), 'short'); ?>`, is it what you want?

Comment: Yes, do I have to add the  t() function for translation?

Comment: Nope, it handles the language automatically as I explained in answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right using the correct API [format_date()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/7.x). What you need to do is passing correct value to it.

```php
<?php print format_date(time(), 'short'); ?>
```

According to the API doc, the function signature is:

```php
format_date($timestamp, $type = 'medium', $format = '', $timezone = NULL, $langcode = NULL)
```

And it explained how you should handle the translation.

> $langcode: (optional) Language code to translate to. Defaults to the language used to display the page.

`$langcode` is handled automatically if you keep it as default value.

Comment: Thank you, Jimmy Ko! This is exactly I was looking for. Now I am able to customize the date format for multiple languages.